# Microstrategy Web API to trigger schedule on a Report?

Tags: microstrategy

Is their any Microstrategy Web API to trigger a schedule on a Report. I have reports which need to be emailed based on certain flags, so I want to remove the flag dependency and directly trigger the schedule from the command line or web API call.

currently not finding any way for this type of triggers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such web api implemented in Micro-strategy yet.But you can use command manager tool to write a trigger script and schedule your reports.